Should I expect statistical analytical problems in this PLS-SEM structure?
Dear all great statisticians ...

I am a doctoral student and my conceptual framework contains five variables. Among these variables are a mediator and a moderator. I am not sure of the validity of the whole framework or if I should eliminate some paths or I just could keep it as it is. I intend to analyze this model after collecting data using the SMARTPLS but I have no idea about if the software would consider it as valid to be analyzed correctly. I also want to know if there any wrong paths that I should consider prior submitting research plan to my supervisor..
I will attach an image for that framework and I hope that you might recommend me to what I should do with its paths.

Welcome to Cross Validated Eyad. The graph looks fine to me (but I'm no expert) but I would tend to think that identifying "wrong paths" is more of a subject matter than a statistical question. Besides, you should not be afraid to submit things to your supervisors, even if they are wrong, that's what supervisors are here for.
